# How to convert table from google sheet into paragraph in google document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm new to the google app script. I was trying to create a google document using google app script, to help me to convert data from the table (from spreadsheet) into paragraphs in google doc.

This is the sample of the [data source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BCgwLkOEGHrhldZjWcbHDrMwacvTyCy6qlirRvtBJLM/edit#gid=0), and this is the [expected output](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12iadydkMIcDxbgliP2mq7u8UJlazwXwwiYy12Xdgq44/edit#) that I want.

What script should I use to make this happen?

thank you for answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet and put them to the Document with the format using Google Apps Script.

In your situation, how about the following flow?

1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet and create an object.
2. Create new Google Document.
3. Using the object, each value is put to the created Document with the format.

When this flow is reflected in a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this sample, please copy and paste it to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet including the values. And, if you want to change `title`, `sectionTitle` and `head`, please modify the script. And, run the function `myFunction`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const title = "DOCUMENT TITLE";
  const sectionTitle = "SECTION TITLE";
  const head = ["ID: ", "EMPLOYEE NAME: "];

  // 1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet and create an object.
  const [headers, ...rows] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();
  const res = rows.map((r) => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, { [h]: r[j] }), {}));

  // 2. Create new Google Document.
  const doc = DocumentApp.create("temp");

  // 3. Using the object, each value is put to the created Document with the format.
  const lineBreak = _ => body.appendParagraph("").editAsText().setBold(false).setFontSize(11);
  const body = doc.getBody()
  body.appendParagraph(title).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).editAsText().setBold(true).setFontSize(20);
  lineBreak();
  res.forEach(e => {
    headers.forEach((h, j) => {
      if (e[h]) {
        if (j < 2) {
          body.appendParagraph(head[j] + e[h]).editAsText().setBold(0, head[j].length - 1, true).setFontSize(11);
          if (j == 1) {
            lineBreak();
            body.appendParagraph(sectionTitle).editAsText().setBold(true).setFontSize(14);
            lineBreak();
          }
        } else if (j == 2) {
          body.appendParagraph(e[h]).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2).editAsText().setBold(true).setFontSize(12);
          lineBreak();
        } else {
          body.appendParagraph(e[h]);
          lineBreak();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

- When you run this script, a new Google Document is created and the values from Spreadsheet are put to the Document. You can see it at the root folder.

#### Note:

- This sample script is from your sample Google Spreadsheet and Google Document. When those are changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#createname)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [appendParagraph(text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendparagraphtext)

### Added:

About your following new question,

> Thanks! This is really helpful. I was wondering if let's say I want to create 1 document for Johnny Depp, and 1 document for Michael Page, and let's say I have more list of names in the table and I want to create 1 document for each person. How will it be?

**From your new question in your comment, I cannot understand the filename of new Document and the values of `title`, `sectionTitle` and `head`. So in this case, please modify them for your actual situation.**

How about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const title = "DOCUMENT TITLE";
  const sectionTitle = "SECTION TITLE";
  const head = ["ID: ", "EMPLOYEE NAME: "];

  const [headers, ...rows] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();
  const res = rows.map((r) => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, { [h]: r[j] }), {}));

  const lineBreak = body => body.appendParagraph("").editAsText().setBold(false).setFontSize(11);
  let body;
  res.forEach((e, i) => {
    headers.forEach((h, j) => {
      if (e[h]) {
        if (j < 2) {
          if (j == 0) {
            const doc = DocumentApp.create(e["Legal Name"]);
            body = doc.getBody()
            body.appendParagraph(title).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).editAsText().setBold(true).setFontSize(20);
            lineBreak(body);
            body.appendParagraph(head[j] + e[h]).editAsText().setBold(0, head[j].length - 1, true).setFontSize(11);
          } else if (j == 1) {
            body.appendParagraph(head[j] + e[h]).editAsText().setBold(0, head[j].length - 1, true).setFontSize(11);
            lineBreak(body);
            body.appendParagraph(sectionTitle).editAsText().setBold(true).setFontSize(14);
            lineBreak(body);
          }
        } else if (j == 2) {
          body.appendParagraph(e[h]).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2).editAsText().setBold(true).setFontSize(12);
          lineBreak(body);
        } else {
          body.appendParagraph(e[h]);
          lineBreak(body);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful.

I was wondering if let's say I want to create 1 document for Johnny Depp, and 1 document for Michael Page, and let's say I have more list of names in the table and I want to create 1 document for each person. How will it be?

Comment: @Nadila Thank you for replying. About your new question, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's as expected :)

Comment: Nadila, please mark the solution post submitted by Tanaike as "Best Answer." This helps the contributor community easily see which issues have been fully resolved. It helps future site visitors quickly find the most relevant answers. (And it is a teeny-tiny mark of appreciation for someone like Tanaike, who clearly spend a great deal of time working out such a solution for you.)

Comment: @Erik Tyler I appreciate your support.

Comment: Hi @ErikTyler will do, thank you!

Comment: Hi @Tanaike I really appreciated your help for this!

Comment: So, I was trying to do the code like you suggest, however, I face some problems when I tried to apply it to my data. The case is happen when I try to generate the code, I expect everyone will only have 1 document for each goals, but it turns out it create multiple document for each person, it turns out 1 goal 1 document where I expect every goals could be compiled to 1 document. I just realized that the data that I use for sample and the actual data is different.

Comment: So the actual data is something like this (tab "data source"). 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BCgwLkOEGHrhldZjWcbHDrMwacvTyCy6qlirRvtBJLM/edit#gid=306000646

Is it because the id and the employee's name is repeated, so that's why the document is also repeating?

Second, I was also need to generate link to each document and paste it in this tab "Link". What script should I use?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BCgwLkOEGHrhldZjWcbHDrMwacvTyCy6qlirRvtBJLM/edit#gid=757847191

Sorry for the questions and the confusion. Again, I really appreciate your help. Thank you @Tanaike

Comment: @Nadila Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike I already mark your answer as accepted in this thread, I hope it's the right thing to do because this is my first time posting in here. As suggested, I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791854/how-to-get-paragraphs-in-google-doc-from-google-spreadsheet-table-and-create-a-l

again, thank you for all the help and assistance, this really helps me a lot :)

Comment: @Nadila Thank you for replying. I would like to check it.