# How to get paragraphs in google doc from google spreadsheet table and create a link for document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749739/how-to-convert-table-from-google-sheet-into-paragraph-in-google-document/69750761?noredirect=1#comment123364336_69750761) I posted. I am new to this site and also to google script, please apologize my knowledge on script. I have two questions that I want to ask:

1. I was assigned a task from my lead to convert table from spreadsheet into paragraphs in a google doc.

Basically, I was assigned to turn this set of [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1crBR49jpuCV-oYAXC_ct3D_iZpvRZJM1Ty3LL9Gz9dI/edit#gid=306000646), into [the expected output](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12iadydkMIcDxbgliP2mq7u8UJlazwXwwiYy12Xdgq44/edit#heading=h.ec2hhzjd3iwj).

While **Employee_ID** and ****Worker information**** is contained only 1 information, ****Goal****, **Description**, **Self-Evaluation**, and **Manager_Comment** might have multiple rows and each person might have different numbers (i.e. some person might only have 1 goal, some others might have 2, 3 or even more). However, I was tasked to create one file for each person, thus I have to put all the goals, description, self-evaluation, and manager_comment of each person in one document.

What script should I use to make this happen?

2. Everytime I generate the document, I was also expecting to generate a link of every document and put it into the tab in a spreadsheet. With the help of google script, I hope I can automatically print each employee's document link in this tab. I put some examples of what I expect [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1crBR49jpuCV-oYAXC_ct3D_iZpvRZJM1Ty3LL9Gz9dI/edit#gid=757847191). Please advice what script that I can use to make this happen.

thank you for answering the question. I highly appreciate it!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between "data source" and "the expected output" and "The document should be consist of:". And also, I cannot understand `I also needed to generate a link to each document and paste it here.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thank you for your prompt response. I have rephrased my question, I hope it's clearer now. I apologize that English is also not my first language.

To answer your question, it's similar to my question in my first thread, however, the spreadsheet data source table is a bit different, and the expected output is also different. I hope it clarifies your question, feel free to let me know if you need any more clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I have one more question. Your current goal shown in your updated question is the final situation. You will not change your goal after the sample script was proposed. Is my understanding correct? Because when I saw your updated output situation, it was changed from your initial provided sample output situation. So I'm worried about this. I apologize for this. If you want to change the output situation, please change it. How about this?

Comment: Hi again, the sample of data that I shared in this question and the previous one is different. If I use your script suggestion from the previous question with this new data source set, it will create multiple document for each person. While, I suppose only create one document for each person.

Comment: This is the previous data set for your reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BCgwLkOEGHrhldZjWcbHDrMwacvTyCy6qlirRvtBJLM/edit#gid=0

This is the new one: (I also change the header name)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1crBR49jpuCV-oYAXC_ct3D_iZpvRZJM1Ty3LL9Gz9dI/edit#gid=306000646

This is the link to the new expected output, I added a title in each paragraph: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12iadydkMIcDxbgliP2mq7u8UJlazwXwwiYy12Xdgq44/edit#heading=h.ec2hhzjd3iwj

I apologize if I still haven't answered your question.

Comment: By the way, where can the value of "Employee_Comment:" in your sample output situation be retrieved? In your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot find the value of "Employee_Comment:".

Comment: I proposed a sample script for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, in order to achieve your goal, I modified [the sample script of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69750761/7108653) as follows. The modification points are as follows.

- In order to use the existing script, I converted the value of `res` for your new situation.
- I added the paragraph name of each paragraph.
- In order to include your 2nd request, the values of "Employee_ID", "Worker" and the URL of created Document are returned from the loop and those values are put to "Link" sheet.

When these are reflected to the sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const title = "DOCUMENT TITLE";
  const sectionTitle = "SECTION TITLE";
  const head = ["ID: ", "EMPLOYEE NAME: "];

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [headers, ...rows] = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data").getDataRange().getValues();
  let w = "";
  const res = rows.map((r, i) => {
    const obj = headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, { [h]: r[j] }), {});
    if (i == 0) {
      w = obj["Worker"];
      return obj;
    }
    if (w != obj["Worker"]) {
      w = obj["Worker"];
    } else {
      obj["Worker"] = "";
      obj["Employee_ID"] = "";
    }
    return obj;
  });

  const lineBreak = body => body.appendParagraph("").editAsText().setBold(false).setFontSize(11);
  let body;
  const values = res.flatMap((e, i) =>
    headers.reduce((ar, h, j) => {
      if (e[h]) {
        if (j < 2) {
          if (j == 0) {
            const doc = DocumentApp.create(e["Worker"]);
            body = doc.getBody()
            body.appendParagraph(title).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).editAsText().setBold(true).setFontSize(20);
            lineBreak(body);
            body.appendParagraph(head[j] + e[h]).editAsText().setBold(0, head[j].length - 1, true).setFontSize(11);
            ar.push([e["Employee_ID"], e["Worker"], doc.getUrl()]);
          } else if (j == 1) {
            body.appendParagraph(head[j] + e[h]).editAsText().setBold(0, head[j].length - 1, true).setFontSize(11);
            lineBreak(body);
            body.appendParagraph(sectionTitle).editAsText().setBold(true).setFontSize(14);
            lineBreak(body);
          }
        } else if (j == 2) {
          body.appendParagraph(e[h]).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2).editAsText().setBold(true).setFontSize(12);
          lineBreak(body);
        } else {
          body.appendParagraph(h + ":");
          body.appendParagraph(e[h]);
          lineBreak(body);
        }
      }
      return ar;
    }, [])
  );

  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Link");
  dstSheet.getRange("A2:C").clearContent();
  dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is from your sample Google Spreadsheet and Google Document. When those are changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- Unfortunately, I cannot find "Employee_Comment:" in your sample output Document. In this case, is that "Self_Evaluation"? This can be found from the header row of the sample Spreadsheet. My proposed script uses this value.

#### References:

- [create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#createname)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [appendParagraph(text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendparagraphtext)

Comment: I have tried this code in my actual data source, and it's working! Thank you so much!
I have already accepted your answer. Unfortunately, I couldn't vote yet, but when I am able to do it, I will vote your answer as the best answer.

Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it :D